# WorkManager OneTimeWorkRequest InitialDelay works after twise the time set

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

## **UPDATE (21-nov-2019)**

```
WorkManager.getInstance(activity).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("test_work",
                                                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                                                PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker::class.java,
                                                        15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                                        .build())
```

Now I'm using PeriodicWork and now `doWork()` called twice even I cancelled uniquettask at first attempt.I'm getting Notification twice and **Checked in Log also It's called twice**.

> Note: It's happen only first time and sometime second time also but not getting third time twice.

```
override fun doWork(): Result {


            if (checkTaskFinished()) {
                Logger.e("checkXXX----Hurrayyyy  ☻♥☺")
                val notificationUtils: NotificationUtils = NotificationUtils(applicationContext)
                notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage("Readddd", "rwaeaeae.", 2)


                WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelUniqueWork("test_work")
            }

    return Result.success()
```

}

> **Library I am using :** `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'`

---

#### **OLD**

I'm facing problem with **WorkManager OneTimeWorkRequest setInitialDelay**.

It's work fine when app is in forground or in recent list. But When I remove App from recent list everything is messed up.

**What I want to achieve ?**
- I want send notification to user after few hours when some task is pending ,so after some R&D start work using **WorkManager** because of It's ability to Schedule Tasks without background service limitation.

> Now below is code snippet which work till app is not removed from recent:

```
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                                .build();

    final OneTimeWorkRequest simpleRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
            .setInitialDelay(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .addTag("simple_work")
            .build();

    WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();

    workManager.beginUniqueWork("simple_work", ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, simpleRequest).enqueue();
```

**Worker class**

```
    public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
    public static final String EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE = "output_message";

    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage("TITLE", "This is a MESSEAGE",2);

        Data output = new Data.Builder()
                .putString(EXTRA_OUTPUT_MESSAGE, "I have come from MyWorker!")
                .build();

        setOutputData(output);

        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }


}
```

> Problem is After Remove It from recent list It's send notification but after double time which I set. for example I set **setInitialDelay 5 minutes** but It's work after 10 minutes.

So ,Please guide me what I do wrong or It's not for schedule task at specific time which I set for once. I don't want to keep repeat work after It's done. I'm create just new after finish first OneTimeWorkRequest so It has to work fine as per documented **beginUniqueWork**.

> **Library I am using :** `implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha11"`

English isn't my native language so pardon me for grammatically mistake:)

Comment: have you found an answer to your question?

Comment: It's some experiment in that project so we dropped that and I didn't try after that so ...

Comment: @Andrea Hi I just started on that work again and still getting same problem I'm using now `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'` . I did update question.

Comment: I have to downgrade the version to 2.1.0 in order for it to work

Comment: Any updates on this? Can't upgrade WorkManager from 2.0.1 to 2.1.0, nor 2.2.0, nor 2.3.4 for this issue

Comment: Sorry that project no longer in production so I'm not working on workmanager. Hope someone give you update :)

Comment: Still got the same problem with latest version androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1
Did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is not clear though please update latest work manager lib to `android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-beta03`

And you can explain me why do u need to enque the unique work ?

```
workManager.beginUniqueWork("simple_work", ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, simpleRequest).enqueue();
```

try to replace it with `workManager.enque(simpleRequest);`  and let me know if worked

Comment: Not working even in latest `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'`